# repeatatively creating sync_super for www-data which is showing high CPU usage

Tags: cpu-load

I am facing same kind of problem of having sync_supers recreated on my server, which are using high CPU usage:

```
4353 www-data 20 0 24392 3888 1012 R 100.0 0.0 13:15.26 [sync_supers]
5268 www-data 20 0 24392 3888 1012 R 100.0 0.0 9:42.56 [sync_supers]
4344 www-data 20 0 24264 3744 876 R 99.7 0.0 70:22.26 [sync_supers]
6792 www-data 20 0 24392 3892 1012 R 85.5 0.0 7:16.08 [sync_supers]
```

I have deleted few but again recreated with different pid.

Please help.
I am not expertised in Ubuntu and linux, so bit difficult to trace the issue.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Be sure to patch any Drupal sites you have running. https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/04/25/drupal_premieres_sequel_to_critically_vulnerability_drupalgeddon2/

Answer (score 1):

It's probably malware. [sync_supers](https://lwn.net/Articles/508212/) was a kernel thread, which should **never** be running as `www-data`, and hardly using any resources. And it should not be in use on a 16.04-system.

So check your backup for malware, and nuke the machine, and reinstall from backups that you have verified is clean. A compromised system should probably not be trusted ever again, as it is difficult to find all backdoors that may have been left there.

Comment: Will you please guide me how to do it. I am using Drupal 7 and amazon linux server.

Comment: That's a fairly broad question in it's own right, but essentially create a new virtual server, and reinstall your application from backups, and make sure to patch it.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered this on stackoverflow but since it is not the place I will just let it here: this just happened to me and the answer is that you have been hacked!

Please check: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=903755 on how to clean a possible backdoor left in some PHP file and here my response on additional steps on how to clean the rest here: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-enterprise-47/troubleshootd-utilizing-high-cpu-and-memory-933116/

I would recommend updating your php and taking other security mesures like not providing your PHP version info and apache version in the server response. Reinstalling the system looks like a very cumbersome none-sense to me...