# ubuntu .syslogs background process which is consuming all CPU

Tags: 14.04, apache2, mysql, syslog

I have a real problem with ubuntu VM CPU. It is a GCP machine, and I have web servers running on these 3 VMs.

TOP command result : 
26271 www-data 20 0 178216 2552 640 S 95.9 0.1 1:22.56 .syslogs

ls -l /proc/26271/exe => 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 0 May 4 20:18 /proc/10012/exe -> /var/tmp/.tmp/.syslogs

You can see that ".syslogs" is consuming a lot of CPU.
I tried reboot many times but still ".syslogs" reappearing after few time.

My environnement :
Server : Ubuntu
Web Server : Apache2
DB : mysql
CMS : Drupal 7

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028367/repeatatively-creating-sync-super-for-www-data-which-is-showing-high-cpu-usage/1028389#1028389 - in short your server has malware. Nuke it from orbit, and reinstall.

Comment: Please check my answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1034130/827938 on how to clean up the malware...